# SQL Server 2008R2, Report Manager

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have problem with connecting to Report Manager. The thing is that under "http://localhost/reportServer_name" i have blank page. I am new to this technology. Can anyone help me?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Server that Reporting services is installed on and go to the Start Menu and find Reporting Services Configuration Manager. when there click on the Report Manager URL and then it will display the Report Manager URL.

[image]